# MySQL Schema Advice

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've written a system to swap and change shifts in work automatically between friends using a basic calendar, some Jquery and MySQL, I just wanted to ask the question; is the way I'm currently storing and accessing the data in the tables completely wrong?

1. Users Table:

   - UID, AI (PK)
   - email, VARCHAR(240)
   - password, VARCHAR(64)
2. Shifts table:

   - UID, AI (PK)
   - user_ID, TINYINT
   - shift_type, TINYINT
   - status, TINYINT (0 = "live", 1 = "deleted", 2 = "swappable")
3. Shift_types table:

   - ID, TINYINT (PK)
   - shift_name, VARCHAR
   - shift_start, VARCHAR (dd/mm/YY ss:MM:hh)
   - shift_end, VARCHAR (dd/mm/YY ss:MM:hh)
4. Swap_offers table:

   - UID, AI (PK)
   - shift_id, INT
   - user_id, INT
   - status, (0 = "open", 1 = "closed")

Currently i'm just using a bunch of awkward INNER JOINS to grab the list of active shift swaps for each person, including multiple joins on the same tables to get the info for the person swapping and the person requesting the swap.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to join this kind of info or am i approaching the schema all wrong?

It's only 10 people so it doesnt have to be perfect but i'm trying to use it as a learning experience.

Comment: How are you linking tables 2 and 3?

Comment: Cannot critique a schema without knowing what the important `SELECTs` are.

Comment: As Rick stated, SELECTs would be fine. Otherwise, sounds about right to me. Multiple JOINs on same table are common as you are looking for different data.